# How to create cell-array in MATLAB and initialize all elements to the same object?

Tags: arrays, matlab, initialization, cell-array

I have a matrix (call it `X`) that is initialized to say `zero(3)`.

I want to change the code so that `X` is a cell array of size (say) `(3,1)` and initialize each element to `zero(3)`.

I can do it with a loop but is there a better way?

```
X = cell(3,1);
for ii=1:numel(X)
    X{ii} = zeros(3);
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with `deal()`.

```
>> [X{1:3, 1}] = deal(zeros(3))

X = 

    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]
```

Comment: Note that this is not safe if `X` already exists. For example if it was defined like this before `[X{1:4, 1}] = deal(zeros(4))`

Answer (score 11):

An alternative way:

```
X = repmat({zeros(3)}, 3, 1);
```

another one:

```
X = cell(3,1);
X(:) = {zeros(3)};
```

Comment: The alternatives have the advantage that the size of X is determined on the same line as the new content. I would prefer them to deal. deal probably is best used in some other connection.

Answer (score 3):

And yet another way:

```
X = {zeros(3)};
X(1:3,1) = X;
```

This solution uses the fact that you can assign to indices that lie beyond the variables size. Matlab will automatically expand in this case.

Similarly:

```
clear X;
X(1:3,1) = {zeros(3)};
```